# what is a .sa file for gcc shared library?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I saw an article in http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1052 where it specifies :

*"Shared libraries consist of two basic parts: the stub and the image. The stub library has an extension of .sa. The stub is the library an executable will be linked to."*

But another reference http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/GCC-HOWTO.html it says

*"shared library files (*.sa for a.out, *.so for ELF) "* - Which I understand like .sa is the shared library to use with a.out format, and .so is to use with latest ELF format.

Due to the lack of clarity here , I am asking the question here - what is .sa file ? And what a stub is for?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I didn't find any .sa file in my latest system. So I wanted to understand what is .sa file here the article talks about. Also the term "stub" here mentions as the shared library (.sa) . But I ealier understood "stub" as part of the executable where it points to the shared libray (.sa or .so).  Just wanted to clarify myself

Comment: It is an ancient thing (a.out shared library) which you should ignore today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That article is very old (1995) and is still dealing with pre-ELF (so called *a.out*) shared libraries.

I forgot the details, but in that prehistoric times, *a.out* shared libraries where not position independent, so every process had -for example- to load the `libc` shared library at the same place using the [uselib(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/uselib) syscall -which is obsolete today- (Today two different processes would [mmap(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) it, as a shared [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) object, at various addresses). The `.sa` file also required conventions for this fixed place. Because of that, making shared libraries was really a nightmare: the fixed address segment[s] that they occupied was to be conventionally defined for the entire system or distribution!

But you really should not care today in 2012 , unless you are interested by history (and then you have to dig several old historical documents which might be difficult to find). All distributions, even some quite old one (e.g. from 2004), are using the ELF format which enable each process to `mmap` its shared libraries as it wish.

Today, you can explore with `/proc/1234/maps` or `/proc/1234/smaps` the memory map of process of pid 1234, and you can easily understand that ELF shared objects are mapped at different places. Read also about [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR)

Answer (score 3):

They're probably both correct but *in their own context.*

The first article dates from 1995 and that was about when Linux adopted ELF in the mainstream (it existed mid 94 but you had to work hard to get it). In fact, it even discusses the fact that ELF is a relative newcomer:

> Even though ELF (the executable and linking format designed for Unix SVR4), which makes creating shared libraries trivial, is just over the horizon, the current a.out DLL shared libraries will probably need to be supported for some time.

So it's probably correct in that all it knew or cared about at the time was the `a.out` format.

The HowTo is dated somewhat later as 1999 and discusses the differences between `a.out` and `ELF` so I would consider it a more reliable source. At that point, ELF had been mainstream for several years.

Of course, that's a relative comparison. The more reliable source is still well over a decade old, talking about gcc 2.7 as if it's the latest and greatest whereas, in fact, we'll well advanced to 4.6.

You may want to consider finding something a little more recent.